# How to catch connection events?

Tags: java, chronicle, hft, chronicle-queue

I am really confused about chronicle's connection interface. 
I couldn't find any test code or source code about it.

I want to catch disconnection and on-connection events.

My setup looks like (vanilla chronicle 3.6.2.);

Two identical process, connects each other.

Source::

```
chronicle = ChronicleQueueBuilder.vanilla(journalerPath).build();
source = ChronicleQueueBuilder
        .source(chronicle)
        .bindAddress("127.0.0.1", port)
        .connectionListener(connListener)
        .build();
appender = source.createAppender();
localReader = chronicle.createTailer();
```

Tailer::

```
remoteChronicle = ChronicleQueueBuilder
        .remoteTailer()
        .connectAddress(remoteSourceHost, remoteSourcePort)
        .connectionListener(connListener)
        .build();
remoteTailer = remoteChronicle.createTailer();
```